# Scrolling option in QEMU

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, qemu

I have compiled a kernel successfully and used `qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel arch/x86/boot/bzImage -initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.14.41+ -m 512M` to boot it. Unfortunately some error throws up and I want to debug it. There are many messages printing but I cannot scroll up to see them. So, how can I get the messages?

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found out an Alternative for this. Used the command `qemu-system-x86_64 -nographic -kernel arch/x86/boot/bzImage -initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.14.41+ -m 512M -append console=ttyS0` and got all the error messages right on the terminal.